# Beginner to Darknet

Tags: help, darknet

I'm new to the amazing hidden world of hidden web. I'm getting some difficulties to understand how things work in there. I have heard that there are many resources in the deep web such as gaming hacks, exclusive things and other stuff like that.
 The problem is that I can't find them on the deep web. I don't know why! Maybe some invite Links are needed.
 **If really such links are needed then can anyone please help me in getting access to them freely?**

Comment: I have spent a good number of years using TOR off and on. I still have not figured out how to find things on the Dark Web. When I do find something, most of the links seem to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

that's why the network is called a "dark" web - there's no public lists that are "listing it all", and there's no mechanism to scan or enumerate all the nodes with HS hosted - in a clearnet you can scan all the IP's to probe for a webserver on an opened ports.